# deploy exceptionless on k8s! Error Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: kubernetes, exceptionless

I get the exceptionless helm chart ,my value.yaml is https://github.com/mypublicuse/myfile/blob/main/el-values.yaml

i got errors
1:
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Deployment.apps "exceptionless-elasticsearch" is invalid: spec.template.spec.initContainers[0].image: Required value

so I edit the elasticsearch.yaml Add
spec:
initContainers:

- name: sysctl
  image: mydockerhost/busybox:1.35

so the helm can install
2: after helm install
i found
exless-nfsclient-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-7fc86846fmlbgz 1/1 Running 0 52m
exceptionless-redis-85956947f-7vkpg 1/1 Running 0 49m
exceptionless-app-6547d4d88d-2hkbg 1/1 Running 0 49m
exceptionless-elasticsearch-76f6cc9b9-2jgks 1/1 Running 0 49m
exceptionless-jobs-web-hooks-7bb9d7477c-kpmwv 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m53s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-event-notifications-844cb87665-bd7bt 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m53s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-mail-message-647d6bd897-s8jmq 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m55s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-event-usage-75c6d6d54d-m5rjr 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m46s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-work-item-c74d77b55-th4g7 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m34s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-daily-summary-6c99dfbc87-7zq5k 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m34s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-event-posts-75777759b8-nsmbw 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m32s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-close-inactive-sessions-b49595f49-hmfxm 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m14s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-event-user-descriptions-5c9d5dc768-8h27z 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m16s ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-stack-event-count-54ffcfb4b6-gk6mz 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 14 (2m ago) 49m
exceptionless-jobs-maintain-indexes-27669970-s28cg 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 5 (94s ago) 4m30s
exceptionless-collector-5c774fd8ff-6ksvx 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 2 (11s ago) 37s
exceptionless-api-66fc9cc659-zckzz 0/1 CrashLoopBackOff 3 (9s ago) 55s

api collector and jobs is un success!

I need help!thanks!

The pod log is
Back-off restarting failed container
yes just it!
i guess the program should be run and immediate crash ,so ....

Comment: the exceptionless url is https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless/tree/main/k8s/exceptionless

Comment: I add the command: ["/bin/bash", "-ce", "tail -f /dev/null"] to api.yaml
then the pod log
Container exceptionless-api failed liveness probe, will be restarted
Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.42.2.120:80/health": dial tcp 10.42.2.120:80: connect: connection refused
Started container exceptionless-api
Created container exceptionless-api

....